# Using IPC as a middle-man to use another package

Tags: node.js, electron

Following [recommendations](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738) I implemented this way of communicating between the renderer and the main process. I now wish to use the package `electron-settings` and am wondering if there is any reason to use this way of communicating to set/get settings.

I have two choices:

- Implementing listeners in main.js (setSetting, getSetting, hasSetting) within which I am calling `settings.set()`, `settings.get()`, `settings.has()` then sending back the result through IPC - essentially wrapping the functions and sanitizing the input.

```js
ipcMain.on("setSetting", (event, key, value) => {
    // Sanitizing input
    settings.set(key, value);
});

ipcMain.on("getSetting", (event, key) => {
    // Sanitizing input
    mainWindow.webContents.send("getSettingResult", settings.get(key));
});

ipcMain.on("hasSetting", (event, key) => {
    // Sanitizing input
    mainWindow.webContents.send("hasSettingResult", settings.has(key));
});
```

- Import the `electron-settings` module within `preload.js` and add it to `module.exports` so that I can use it in the renderer process. I would assume this is a potential breach?

What is the best way to go about that? Does it matter?
If I had to apply that to other packages, should I create "wrappers" in the form of listeners for every possible action?

Comment: after reading you link, if you highly concern about your security , i think the first option is most suitable

Comment: This is a version of what I ended up doing. Posting the answer below. I'm not sure that's the most elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I went with:

### main.js

```js
ipcMain.on("setSetting", (event, key, value) => {
    // Sanitizing input
    settings.set(key, value);
});

ipcMain.on("getSetting", (event, key) => {
    // Sanitizing input
    event.returnValue = settings.get(key);
});

ipcMain.on("hasSetting", (event, key) => {
    // Sanitizing input
    event.returnValue = settings.has(key);
});
```

### renderer.js

```js
let value = window.api.sendSync("getSetting", "testSetting");

window.api.send("setSetting", "testSetting", "test");
```

This has the disadvantage of being synchronous but I couldn't think of another way to make sure the result goes to the right asynchronous listener. Even with `event.reply` if I was sending two `getSetting` every listener would get the same answer.